# Web Scraping 24/7 without Ip-spoofing (theoretical) - Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, theory

**Now before I ask the actual question I want to mention that IP-Spoofing is illegal in a number of Countries so please do not attempt to use any code provided in here or in the answers bellow. Moreover I am not confident myself that I know exactly what is considered legal and what not in the subject I'm about to open therefor I want to state that every piece of code provided here has not and will not be actually tested. Everything just should 'theoretically work'!**

Having mentioned that, a friend of mine asked me if I could make a bot that would monitor a market 24/7 and shall it find an item in the desired price (or lower) it will automatically buy it. Now the only problem in theory that I think my code would have is in this line here:

```
request(url, some_var_name, timeout=1) 
#think that timeout will need to be at least 2 realistically but anyway!
```

This **runs in a loop that's supposed to run 24/7 sending *1 request per second (optimally)*** to the server. After a while the most likely outcome is that this will be viewed as a DDoS attack and to prevent it the IP will be blocked so we wont be able to get the prices from the request anymore. An easy solution would be Proxies, just have a list of them bought from somewhere or even get some for free possibly infecting your own computer with something or getting all your requests monitored by someone but yeah.. That's one *(illegal I think)* way to achieve that.. Now questions I have are:

Is there a way to achieve the same result without proxies? And is there a way to make the whole thing legal so I can actually test it out on a real market?

Thanks in advance y'all, if at the end I find out that there's nothing to be done here at the very least it was a fun challenge to take on!

Comment: `After a while the most likely outcome is that this will be viewed as a DDoS attack` - at 1 request per second this is hardly an "attack", also it's not distributed if it's coming from one client. IP-based rate-limiting is the least of a scalper bot's problems. For one, the `requests` client does not execute JavaScript as it's just a simple HTTP client, and that alone would prevent it from working on any half-decent online marketplace.

Comment: You can use ProxyPoolPlugin https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py#proxypoolplugin to get the desired effect locally.  Essentially, you run a local proxy, which tunnel your requests via a pool of upstream proxies that you define.  These upstream proxies can be cloud instances in different geo-locations.